# Unable to display images using Node.js, Express, and EJS

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am working on building my views for a project, and I am running into so trouble getting images to render on my .ejs pages. When the page loads, there is just a little page icon next to the alt text I set in the ejs file. I'm also getting a "GET /public/images/ResConnect.png 404" error in the console. I've tried some solutions online, but nothing seems to work. Here is the code for the specific page I'm trying to get a logo to render on:

```
<!-- views/index.ejs -->
    <!doctype html>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>ResConnect Home</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <!-- load bootstrap css -->
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/solid.js" integrity="sha384-+Ga2s7YBbhOD6nie0DzrZpJes+b2K1xkpKxTFFcx59QmVPaSA8c7pycsNaFwUK6l" crossorigin="anonymous"></script> <!-- load fontawesome -->
        <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.8/js/fontawesome.js" integrity="sha384-7ox8Q2yzO/uWircfojVuCQOZl+ZZBg2D2J5nkpLqzH1HY0C1dHlTKIbpRz/LG23c" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <style>
            body        { padding-top:80px; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="jumbotron text-center">
                <img src="./public/images/ResConnect.png" alt="ResConnect Logo"/>
                <h1><span class="fa fa-lock"></span> ResConnect Home</h1>
                <p>Please advise: Only approved personnel by The University of Mississippi Department of Student Housing may access ResConnect.</p>

                <b>Login or Register with:</b><br>

                <a href="/login" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> Login</a>
                <a href="/signup" class="btn btn-default"><span class="fa fa-user-plus"></span> Register</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here's my server.js file:

```
// server.js

// get all the tools we need
var express  = require('express');
var session  = require('express-session');
var favicon = require('express-favicon');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var app      = express();
var port     = process.env.PORT || 1848;

var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');


require('./config/passport')(passport); // pass passport for configuration

app.use(favicon(__dirname + './public/images/favicon.ico'));
app.use(express.static('./public/images'));

// set up our express application
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // set up ejs for templating

// required for passport
app.use(session({
    secret: 'vidyapathaisalwaysrunning',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
 } )); // session secret

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session()); // persistent login sessions
app.use(flash()); // use connect-flash for flash messages stored in session


require('./app/routes.js')(app, passport); 

app.listen(port);
console.log('Server running on port ' + port);
```

And here is my get function for the index.ejs page I'm rendering:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('index.ejs'); // load the index.ejs file
});
```

Additionally, here is my directory setup for the project, so that you can see where all of my files are:

[Project file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dzNHz.png)

Comment: Maybe you need `/public` instead of `./public` - in the HTML? EDIT; wasn't reading closely enough. express.static isn't considering public/images to be part of the uri for the files it serves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change

```
app.use(express.static('./public/images'));
```

to be

```
app.use('/public/images/', express.static('./public/images'));
```

You need express to serve files from the filesystem at ./public/images, but you need to serve those files from the uri under /public/images (instead of just '/')

For example in http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html note how the static middleware serves from 'public' but the uris in the sample do not include 'public'.

Adding a path as the argument to any `.use` mounts the middleware under the given path.

--- EDIT to support favicon.ico not served underneath /public/images

You can alternatively update the directory structure you are using;

```
app.use(express.static('/path/to/content'));
```

where `/path/to/content` contains

```
 /
 |-> favicon.ico
 |-> public/
     |-> images/
         |-> x.png
         |-> y.png
```

So keep in mind express.static serves whatever is inside the path you pass it, at the route it is mounted at (by default '/'). The path it reads from has no bearing on the uris, but *the directory structure inside does*

Comment: Is there a reason why after I fixed this that my favicon is no longer showing up? I'm getting a `GET /favicon.ico 404` error in my console now. The favicon is in the same folder as the images.

Comment: @BlakeLewis yes, all files inside that folder will be served underneath '/public/images/'. That will break the favicon. I will update the answer with another possible way of going that can support both

Comment: For your edit, that was what I originally had and it was not loading images that way. So when I have `app.use(express.static('/public/images'));

app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));` the favicon and images do not render

Comment: @BlakeLewis option two isn't really great because it will mean `express.static` serves all GET requests to `/`, which will interfere with your favicon middleware and any custom routes.

Comment: `app.use(favicon(__dirname + './public/images/favicon.ico'));` should be working. Let me check further. Note that the way you had it probably is not what I have in the edit unless your actual directory structure is `public/images/public/images`

Comment: Not sure @BlakeLewis, unless `favicon.ico` isn't actually at that path

Comment: Yeah, I will probably stick with option 1 because that's what's getting my pictures to load, I'm sure I can figure out a way to get this favicon to load. Right now I just have it this way: `app.use('/public/images/', express.static('./public/images')); app.use(favicon(__dirname + './public/favicon.ico'));`